# Setting background colour of a column depending on time using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have five columns each with a different time, I want to highlight the column which is before the time in the next column. They are all in time order, from earliest to latest.

To put this into context, column A has a time of 8AM, column B has a time or 12PM, column C has a time of 3PM, column D has a time of 6PM, and column E has a time of 9PM. So, if the current time was 2PM, column B should be highlighted until the time is 3PM, where column C becomes highlighted.

Each column is defined using a class, and each time is retrieved from a JSON file.

It's my understanding that I would have to use getElementsByClassName and iterate over the collection, as each result would yield a collection. However, this would target all the columns, rather than just a specific one.

This is what I have so far in terms of my JavaScript code. Note, I am **not** using jQuery.

**Javascript**

```
var h = addZero(currentDate.getHours());
var m = addZero(currentDate.getMinutes());
var s = addZero(currentDate.getSeconds());
var time = h + timeSeparator + m + timeSeparator + s;

if (time >= timetables[i].sunrise || time >= timetables[i].lunchtime) {
        var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
            for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                cols[i].style.background = '#ba4346';
            }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
       <section id="times">
        <div class="container cf">
            <div class="column">
                <p id="sunrise">Sunrise</p>
                <div class="separator"></div>
                <p id="sunrise-time" class="time">undefined</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <p id="lunchtime">Lunchtime</p>
                <div class="separator"></div>
                <p id="lunchtime-time" class="time">undefined</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: what is all the addZero and timeSeparator stuff? is time a String? if so, you won't be able to compare it with a time (assuming that is what is in `timetables`) with `>=`. Could you post your html as well?

Comment: @thedarklord47 that just creates a time string such as 00:58, and yeah I'll update the post with that now.

Comment: so the `<p>` with `class="time"` is where the time string is inserted (in place of undefined)?

Comment: If all you care about is the hour you can use `var hour = new Date().getHours()` which, right now, gives me `17` since it's 5:12pm in my time-zone. Prefixing with 0 turns a number into a string — numbers are easier to work with when comparing values, so no need to _addZero()_.

Comment: @thedarklord47 Sort of. "sunrise-time" would the ID that is targeted. Like this `for (var i = 0; i < timetables.length; i++) { if (timetables[i].date == dateFormatted) {
            document.getElementById("sunrise-time").innerHTML = timetables[i].sunrise;`

Answer (score 0):

## You can use .getHours() function

Just create a new variable date and than use `.getHour()` on it to get the value of the hour.

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
// and you have the current hours stored in a variable named h;

// now you can compare the hour with whatever you want and do whatever you want, e.g:
if (0 <= d <= 6 || 18 <= d <= 23) {
  alert("it's night.");
} else {
  alert("it's day.")
};


//changing background:
if (0 <= d <= 6 || 18 <= d <= 23) {
  document.getElementById("columnId").style.background = "blue";
} else {
  document.getElementById("column2Id").style.background = "yellow";
};
```

Tell me if you have problems and on what you have.
If you need to manipulate the DOM I really suggest you to use JQuery it's much easier, and it's just an HTTP request more than using normal JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to have a way of "checking the time" that is currently in each column.

```
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
for(var i=0; i<cols.length; i++){
    //get the string from each column
    var colTime = cols[i].children[2].innerHTML
    if (colTime < currTime){
        cols[i].style.background = '#ba4346';
    }
}
```

This will not work as is, because your time is displayed as a funky string. If you have access to the JSON object that you use to populate the columns, that would work alot better.

That way, rather than doing the funky innerHTML thing to pull your data out, then decode it, then do the comparison, you would just do something like this:

```
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
for(var i=0; i<cols.length; i++){
    if (jsonColumnData[i] < currTime){
        cols[i].style.background = '#ba4346';
    }
}
```

Much better.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point about the funky formatting. So what you're suggesting is, format the time correctly (e.g. 15:32, rather than 3:32 PM) in the JSON file then loop over it like you suggested above. Would there be anyway of formatting the text afterwards? I'd much prefer it if the time column read as "2:20 PM" than "14:40".

Comment: Okay so I've made use of the Moment.js library in order to format the dates in the columns from epoch time to a string, vs. what I was doing previously with the funky formatting. Here's a link to a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kzp3x35S). This doesn't seem to change the colour of the column though. :(

Comment: use my second suggestion. in the json, keep the time in an easy to compare format (i.e. Moment.js). That way you can use my second code snippet to compare each columns json data to the current time and color your columns accordingly.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to work. I've figured out a less elegant solution which I've posted as an answer. Feel free to have a look and make any suggestions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering, I've managed to work out my own solution.

For each column, I assigned a div ID which allows each column to be targeted individually.

```
<div class="column" id="sunrise">
    <p id="sunrise-caption">Sunrise</p>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <p id="sunrise-time" class="time">undefined</p>
</div>
```

I converted all the non-standard time formats in each array in my JSON file to Epoch times. Following this, I wrote if statements for each column ID, checking whether or not the time is greater than or equal to the epoch time assigned in the JSON file.

```
if (time >= timetables[i].sunrise) {
    document.getElementById("sunrise").style.background = red;
    document.getElementById("sunset").style.background = "none";
}
```

In order to retain the easy to read time formatting in the columns v.s. epoch times, I used the `moment.unix` method to format the epoch times to a human readable one.

Maybe not the cleanest solution, but it seems to work well. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: this is essentially what I was proposing in my answer. Use epoch time in your JSON, then compare that to the current time. I would suggest selecting by class and doing this comparison in a loop though. The individual ID thing is very fragile/rigid.